# Kotlin JavaScript Karma test fails to make any http requests

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm running JavaScript tests using Karma but it fails to make http requests.

`build.gradle.kts`

```
js(IR) {
    useCommonJs()
    browser {
        testTask {
            useKarma {
                useChromeHeadless()
            }
        }
    }
    binaries.executable()
}
```

I'm using Ktor Client to fetch the url content

```
val text = HttpClient(Js).get("https://www.google.com/") {
    header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    header("Accept", "*/*")
}.body<String>()
```

And this is the error:

```
> Task :jsTestClasses
> Task :compileTestDevelopmentExecutableKotlinJs
> Task :jsTestTestDevelopmentExecutableCompileSync
> Task :jsBrowserTest
myTest before fetch
TRACE: Adding Accept-Charset=UTF-8 to https://www.google.com/TRACE: Processing exception Error_0: Fail to fetch for request https://www.google.com/Error_0: Fail to fetch
    at http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:52793:26
Caused by: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at commonFetch (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:52730:13)
    at $executeCOROUTINE$16.doResume_5yljmg_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:52105:29)
    at JsClientEngine.execute_95skru_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:52224:16)
    at HttpClientEngine$executeWithinCallContext$slambda.doResume_5yljmg_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:46100:44)
    at HttpClientEngine$executeWithinCallContext$slambda.invoke_1yhb3o_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:46082:16)
    at l (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:46133:16)
    at _no_name_provided__qut3iv_6.doResume_5yljmg_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:31198:43)
    at CoroutineImpl.resumeWith_7onugl_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:31062:33)
    at CoroutineImpl.resumeWith_s3a3yh_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:31108:17)
    at DispatchedTask.run_mw4iiu_k$ (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_293805/commons.js?58a2b80ce49dc5767b060dfe37192606438b082a:41652:24)
```

Trying to make the same request using `window.fetch`:

```
val response = window.fetch(url).await()
println("response: ${response.body}")
```

This fails with:

```
> Task :jsTestTestDevelopmentExecutableCompileSync
> Task :jsBrowserTest
getFileText before fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at 2.doResume_5yljmg(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:3883)
    at <global>.httpGet(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:3765)
    at 1.doResume_5yljmg(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:3845)
    at HtmlResourceLoader.getFileText_6u54xq(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:3920)
    at slambda.doResume_5yljmg(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:992)
    at slambda.invoke_pbb09x(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:978)
    at slambda.$block(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:1023)
    at slambda.doResume_5yljmg(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:3792)
    at slambda.invoke_d6gbsu(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:3778)
    at <global>.l(/var/folders/cb/nd4gn6pn79zg52rz_l5bl1bdjfnmjy/T/_karma_webpack_124481/commons.js:3825)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable cors in Express server.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html